# cMake/cTest: Check if code compiles

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, ctest

I would like to check if my code compiles or not. In my cMakeList.txt I defined my source_files with `file()`

Is there any chance to pass this variable to the module CheckCXXSourceCompiles?

It is like doing a test like that:

```
check_cxx_source_compiles("int main() { return 0;}" DUMMY)
```

but obviously for all `${source_files}`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`try_compile`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atry_compile) command:

```
try_compile(COMPILE_SUCCEEDED ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_tests my_test_src.cpp)

if(COMPILE_SUCCEEDED)
  message("Success!")
endif()
```

Mind you that this is only really useful for compiling small test programs that check for a specific compiler feature. The quickest way to find out if your main codebase compiles is still to actually *build it*. There is really no need to worry about this during configure phase.

Comment: Thank you.I found another solution based on cTest.